# How to get webPart settings from an string array?

Tags: web-part

I am building a custom webpart. I have also created some generic config class where I get the webPart provisioning settings by current webTemplate internal name. I only need to know how to get the seperated attributes from my string array?

See example of code below:

```
string[] webTemplateSettings = new string[] { "template:SPSPERS#2,pageUrl:Social/Sites.aspx,webPartZone:LeftZone,title:Site Lidmaatschap", "template:SITEDEFINITIONTEAM#0,pageUrl:Pages/Default.aspx,webPartZone:LeftZone,title:Site Lidmaatschap" };

                        string currentWebTemplateInternalName = GetCurrentWebTemplate(); // for example: SITEDEFINITIONTEAM#0

                        foreach (string webTemplateSetting in webTemplateSettings)
                        {
                            // Get settings for current webTemplate
                            if (webTemplateSetting.StartsWith(string.Format("template:{0}", currentWebTemplate)))
                            {
                                // split settings
                                string[] webTemplateDetailSettings = webTemplateSetting.Split(",".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                                string pageUrl = ?
                                string webPartZone = ?
                                string title = ?

                                // do something
                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read it from array using array index

```
string pageUrl = webTemplateDetailSettings[1];
string webPartZone = webTemplateDetailSettings[2];
string title = webTemplateDetailSettings[3];
```

Comment: isnt there another way to do this without having 2 arrays and looping into the first array?